# React-Route did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

i'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@SamuelRobertso6/lets-learn-with-the-react-redux-starter-kit-part-1-a3512e553ca1) step by step but when i run "npm run start" i get the next error:

> Warning: [react-router] Location "/todolist" did not match any routes

Any advice to fix that?

Comment: Add your routes

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the route definition.

In your index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToDoComponent,HomeComponent} from './components';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
        <Route path="/todolist" component={ToDoComponent} />
      </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did was define my route in src/routes/index.js, something like this:

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/PageLayout/PageLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import CounterRoute from './Counter'
import TodoListRoute from './TodoList'

/*  Note: Instead of using JSX, we recommend using react-router
PlainRoute objects to build route definitions.   */

export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  component   : CoreLayout,
  indexRoute  : Home,
  childRoutes : [
    TodoListRoute(store), // Here's the trick
    CounterRoute(store)
  ]
})

export default createRoutes
```